# Powershell file printing question_hun

Tags: powershell

I have a question for you

I would like to print the last file in a direction and therefore I made a script, but it is not working as good as I want.

1. I have made a varriable

   ```
   $lastfile = Get-ChildItem S:\HUPRT04 | Select-Object LastWriteTime, Name, FullName | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1
   ```
2. and it works well, but when I wanted to print this pdf I got this message back:

   ```
   the system cannot find the file
   ```

   (but I do not know why)

the print command was this:

```
Start-Process -Path $filepath -Verb print
```

I hope somebody will able to help me.

Best regards:

Comment: you are sure that $filepath contains what you expect it to contain? Maybe you simply should do: start-process -path $lastfile.FullName -verb print

Comment: You store the file path, name and timestamp in a variable called `$lastfile` but then you attempt to pass a completely different variable `$filepath` to `Start-Process`. You should probably do `Start-Process -LiretalPath $lastfile.FullName -Verb Print` instead

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you, and it works well. I wanted to write $lastfile in the question. The solution was the -LiteralPath $lastfile.Fullname